# Crashing On TableView insertRowsAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios5, crash

My app was running fine, I've not modified it to have a dedicated data controller class rather than the data being handled in the main UI class as it was during initial testing. However since the change it keeps crashing when adding a new item to the tableview.

The line of code and error it's crashing on are;

```
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

> 2012-07-22 07:17:44.772 speecher[1897:707] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:
>   'attempt to insert row 0 into section 0, but there are only 0 rows in
>   section 0 after the update'

The full code for that class, (the main MasterViewController class) is as follows.

```
//
//  SpeecherMasterViewController.m
//  speecher
//
//

#import "SpeecherMasterViewController.h"
#import "SpeecherDataController.h"
#import "SpeecherDetailViewController.h"

@interface SpeecherMasterViewController () {

    NSString *newTitle;
    NSMutableArray *_speeches;
    NSMutableArray *_content;
    SpeecherDataController *object;

}
@end

@implementation SpeecherMasterViewController

@synthesize detailViewController = _detailViewController;

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
    self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320.0, 600.0);
    [super awakeFromNib];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(insertNewObject:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
    self.detailViewController = (SpeecherDetailViewController *)[[self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject] topViewController];
    object = [[SpeecherDataController alloc] init];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}


#pragma mark - Table View

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [object returnNoObjects];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    cell.textLabel.text = [object returnTitle:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [_speeches removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    } else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
    }
}

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    NSString *titleobj = [object returnTitle:indexPath.row];
    NSString *contentobj = [object returnContent:indexPath.row];
    self.detailViewController.detailItem = titleobj;
    self.detailViewController.detaitContent = contentobj;
}



- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender
{
    //Make sure clear before we start, also make sure initalized (double redundancy with clear statement at end)
    newTitle = @"";

    //New Title pop up UIAlert View
    UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                           initWithTitle:@"New Speech" 
                           message:@"Please enter a name for speech" 
                           delegate:self 
                           cancelButtonTitle:@"Create" 
                           otherButtonTitles:nil];

    alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;

    UITextField * alertTextField = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];

    alertTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;

    alertTextField.placeholder = @"Enter a new title";
    [alert show];


}



- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{ 
    newTitle = [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] text];

    [object addNewContent:newTitle :@"IT REALLY WORKS!" :@"Nothing"];

        //create new speech title, add to array and add to tableview
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

    //Clear newTitle for use next time
    newTitle = @"";

}

@end
```

EDIT:

Amended to add `[object addNewContent]` method & class as per comments,

```
//
//  SpeecherDataController.m
//  speecher
//
//

#import "SpeecherDataController.h"

@interface SpeecherDataController ()
{
    NSMutableArray *titles;
    NSMutableArray *content;
    NSMutableArray *timer;
}
@end

@implementation SpeecherDataController

-(void) addNewContent:(NSString*)sTitle : (NSString*)sContent :(NSString*)sTimer
{
    [titles insertObject:sTitle atIndex:0];
    [content insertObject:sContent atIndex:0];
    [timer insertObject:sTimer atIndex:0];
}


//Methods to return data
-(NSString*) returnTitle:(NSUInteger)row
{
    return [titles objectAtIndex:row];
}

-(NSString*) returnContent:(NSUInteger)row
{
    return [content objectAtIndex:row];
}

-(NSString*) returnTimer:(NSUInteger)row
{
    return [timer objectAtIndex:row];
}

-(NSInteger) returnNoObjects
{
    return titles.count;
}



@end
```

Comment: I can't see any errors in the code you provided, however looking at the message you are getting, and at the 'tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:' method, I'd guess that your '[object returnNoObjects]' method is not returning the right number of rows (0 in this case).

Comment: @NSArray You almost right. When looking into that I discovered the `[object addNewContent]` function isn't actually adding the content. Question amended to show that function too.

Comment: Try printing out the values of your 'titles' array after you add an object. If its not allocated, you will want to do what JamesKraw has suggested.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I am JamesKraw. I solved issue so answer the question myself :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the NSMutableArrays hadn't been alloc and init. Had to add a check to see if they had a init and alloc if not. New check looks like this,

```
-(void) addNewContent:(NSString*)sTitle : (NSString*)sContent :(NSString*)sTimer
{

    if(!titles)
    {
        titles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    if(!content)
    {
        content = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    if(!timer)
    {
        timer = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }

    [titles insertObject:sTitle atIndex:0];
    [content insertObject:sContent atIndex:0];
    [timer insertObject:sTimer atIndex:0];
}
```